# unable to iterate over json object using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am new to AJAX/JQuery/JSON, I am using Struts 2 to get a JSON object using AJAX, I can see the object returned but I am unable to iterate over it. The returned object is a list that has just one object(may contain more objects), also every object contains a list of some other object.

This is how the js file looks like:

```
$.getJSON('GetAllSaleItemsAction', {
        customerName : debtorSelection
    }, function(jsonResponse){
        //alert(jsonResponse);

        //populate table
        var trHtml = '';
        //$("tr:has(td)").remove();
        jsonResponse = jsonResponse.saleItemsList;

        var responseString = JSON.stringify(jsonResponse);
        console.log(responseString);

        $.each(jsonResponse, function(i, item) {
            var saleEntries = $.parseJSON(item.singleSaleEntries);

            var saleEntriesString = JSON.stringify(saleEntries);
            console.log(saleEntriesString);

            var sseString = '';
            $.each(saleEntries, function(n, sse){
                sseString += sse.item + ' ' + sse.quantity + ' x ' + sse.price + ' = ' + sse.amount;
            });

            trHtml+= '<tr><td>' + item.date + '</td><td>' + sseString + '</td><td>' + item.saleAmount  + '</td><td>' + item.interest  + '</td><td>' + item.totalAmount + '</td></tr>';
        });
        if(trHtml != ''){
            $('#saleRecordTable').append(trHtml);
        }
    });
```

Here the first console.log is executed but not the second console.log as javascript inside the each-function is not executed:

```
[{"customerName":"Tester","date":"2015-02-16T17:36:19","debtorId":1,"interest":0,"saleAmount":14000,"saleId":3,"singleSaleEntries":[{"amount":9000,"item":"DAP_50KG","price":900,"quantity":10,"saleEntry":null,"singleSaleId":4},{"amount":5000,"item":"UREA_50KG","price":500,"quantity":10,"saleEntry":null,"singleSaleId":5}],"totalAmount":14000}]
```

Please guide me.

Comment: What's the problem/error? You probably also need to parse `sse` as JSON.

Comment: Open up your javascript console and to `console.log($.parseJSON(jsonResponse));` and possibly for each `$.parseJSON(item.singleSaleEntries)` That way you can see in console how they are built up

Comment: check the json is valid or not? using jQuery.parseJSON(data)

Comment: added the structure of json object

Comment: @Spokey: I am unable to get to that point, the first line itself is not executed :(

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding that json, could you do JSON.stringify() on it and paste the string?

Comment: Show the full ajax code to be sure you are looping the data within response handler and not outside of it

Comment: @Spokey logged the JSON.stringify()

Comment: @charlietfl added more js for better understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with `var saleEntries = $.parseJSON(item.singleSaleEntries);`
After changing this statement to `var saleEntries = item.singleSaleEntries;`

everything works fine, the problem was that the debug point was set to next statement and because of error in this line, the control was never reaching there.